# Close bottom sheet on tap outside

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, scaffold

I have screen, where I open bottom modal sheet. I call following function:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet();
```

I need to use this method, **I cannot use any other method for showing modal sheet**. What I want to achieve is, that when I click outside the sheet, the sheet is closed. Currently, if I have i.e. `Button` on the screen behind the sheet, I can click the button. How can I achieve this? I tried to find some setting like `isDismissible` in the `showBottomSheet` function, however I did not find anything like it. I also tried to wrap content of the modal sheet with `GestureDetector`, but that did not work either. Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: If it is not possible, please advise how to achieve "locking" the layout behind the modal, so it is not clickable at all.

Comment: You can't use any other method? Not even [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)?

Comment: Please checkout this example it might help you :- https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-close-a-persistent-bottom-sheet-programatically-in-flutter

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I have some widgets at the bottom of the screen. Widgets, that are not a part of that Scaffold, in which I show the bottom sheet. showModalBottomSheet would overlay everything on the screen (also widgets that are not part of that exact Scaffold). I want to keep the question as simple as possible, I hope I explained it better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your bottom sheet content in a [`TapRegion`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegion-class.html), then pop the context in [`TapRegion.onTapOutside`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegion/onTapOutside.html):

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(
  (context) => TapRegion(
    onTapOutside: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    child: Container(), // Your content
  ),
);
```

If you need to propagate tap events through to a button behind the bottom sheet, check out [`TapRegion.consumeOutsideTaps`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegion/consumeOutsideTaps.html)